# Implement abstract class when target already implements one

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

Some of my classes has the same code for error storage. Being two error properties (number and message) and several methods for setting the error state. This code repeats on every class, so today I decided to refactor the common code and extract it so it can be reused.

First I tried to create it as an interface, but I could make it work. On my VB.net programmer mind I thought that it was simple matter of moving the code and referencing it. But interfaces could not handle the code.
So I created an abstract class and started to inherit on my other classes.

```
public class DBEngine : ErrorContainer, IDisposable {
  protected DBEngine(string connectionString, string providerName)
  public DBEngine(string connectionString = "")
}
```

But then I came to a problem when on of my classes already has an inheritance.

```
public abstract class TypedTable<TRow> : TypedTableBase<TRow> where TRow : TypedRow {
  protected TypedTable(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
  protected TypedTable()
}
```

If I inherit the interface, it wants me to re implement all the functions, that seems to me counter-productive.

How I can structure my error storage code, so it can be reused on my classes, even when they already have an inheritance, but avoiding rewriting any code?

NOTE: Please don't confuse what I'm talking there with some Error Handling. For Error handling I use NLog and have my own interface layer and static implementation.
What I'm talking there it's to reuse some properties that several classes have in common, that happens to store the error code and message. Nothing more.

```
   ClassA
     L public Property1
     L public Property2
     L private MethodToSet1And2

   ClassB : Something (problem there)
     L public Property1
     L public Property2
     L private MethodToSet1And2
```

Same two properties and and method.

The answers are out of scope as the proposed solutions isolate the properties from the caller of A and B. The real use of them is precisely pass to the caller some info. Not do some external reusable action.

Comment: The error handling should probably be extracted out into a class dedicated to that alone and then each other class can have an instance of that.

Comment: But processes consuming the service (DBEngine) should also see the ErrorManager properties, as they where part of it. Like if (DbEngine.ErrorNumber !=0) ProcessTheError(DbEngine.Error());

Comment: According S from SOLID principles, none of your such classes be doing error management. As other guys pointed out, you should move error mgmt code into a totally new class. You can create an *interface* for that defines what error mgmt class will do. Then use constructor or property injection to supply error mgmt class instance from calling code. Moreover, error handling code seems to be independent of the object states, so you can also opt for simple static class.

Comment: Use extension methods to 'add' methods (with implementation) to your interface. You can set the extension-method-class to internal if necessary, then you the assembly where you define the extension-method-class can use the extension method.

Answer (score 2):

There's a common practice called ["Composition over inheritance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) (or "Composite Reuse Principle"). This means that instead of an "is-a" relationship, you move to a "has-a" relationship.

What this means in this case is that you'll have a dedicated class which handles common errors, like this:

```
public inteface IErrorHandler
{
    void HandleError(string errorMessage);
}

public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    public void HandleError(string errorMessage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Now each of your classes takes this as a parameter via it's constructor and can use it internally for error handling, meaning you *delegate* the work to it whereever needed:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IErrorHandler errorHandler;
    public Foo(IErrorHandler errorHandler)
    {
        this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        // do stuff
        errorHandler.HandleError("Everything went wrong!");
    }
}
```

Comment: How Foo is consumed? I must pass a new errorHandler to it? My classes already have some complex constructors...

Comment: `Foo` is consumed like any other class you have in your code. It's just an example.

Comment: OP - see my comment on your original question. @Yuval has nicely explained how to do it. If you cannot change constructors, you can have a property of type IErrorHandler and set it from calling code.

Comment: I think I still don't understand it. My error management class and interface is defined like @Yuval s code. And it's located on a separate assembly. What I don't get, is what's the improvement if, for example, my web project, that was ignorant of anything but DBEngine in it's assembly, now has to be aware of the ErrorManagement assembly, and create a new EM object and pass it to DBEngine. Refactor all of the 2034 calls only in one project. (when I only wanted to reuse the code without penalizing all the project)

Comment: @Sergio This is a "fallback", since your *already have* an inheritance call-chain. You can't inherit multiple classes, and implementing an interface will cause you to re-implement the entire logic, which you stated that you don't want.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I must create a new instance of EM and pass it to DBE when instantiating it (yes/no?) or I'll still use my calling code as: using (var db = new DBEngine(Connection))
         {
                db.DoSomething();
                if (db.ErrorNumber != 0)
                    SetError(db.ErrorMessage, db.ErrorNumber);
....

Comment: Yes, you'll have to pass an instance. Another way of handling this is *not handling errors* inside your `DBEngine` class, and allowing them to propogate to a common place higher up the call stack.

Comment: Please, see the real utility of my EM code. It doesn't do anything, it only stores error info externally and internally has code for setting the properties and do some simple log.
It has to be persisted on the DBEngine class so it can be read from the DBE caller. Your errorHandler does something and then (for the DBE caller, disappears)

Comment: @Sergio Use a DI container and abstract factories. If your classes have complex constructors it usually means that the classes are too complex and should be refactored. The main responsibility of a constructor is setting up dependencies, like in the code Yuval posted.

Comment: @Sergio It makes absolutely no sense for `DBEngine` to inherit `ErrorManager`.

Comment: I don't know how to DI and this project it's some old ERP I maintain. I think that seems like trying to kill flies with a machine gun.

Comment: @Sergio I agree. If this is legacy code, it may be an overkill. One possibility is have the implementation error handling logic inside a class, which is then consumed by your abstract base class *and* is also used inside that same class where you can't inherit.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Why not? Excuse me. I'm feeling stupid. As you point something that seems obvious (as you don't tell why) but I still don't get it.
I have 5 classes that each of them have the same errorNumber and errorMessage (apart from some set methods) why I couldn't want them to inherit and share those code?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov You mean, creating a join abstract class that inherits TypedTableBase in this case, and also has the EM code...

Comment: @Sergio Perhaps you want to reconsider why you have these properties multiple times in all those classes. It doesn't make since because inheritance matches an "is-a" relationship. Is your `DBEngine` an `ErrorManager` as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91725/discussion-between-sergio-and-yuval-itzchakov).

Comment: My DBEngine class it's a database layer. Something rougher but like EF context.
It has methods for executing stmts, and doing ADO stuff.
If some error occurs inside, the error management code gets the error and registers it on the error properties and can be read from the callers and do whatever it's necessary. (like I posted above)
All my other classes, mainly disposable ones, have the same code. So the error processing in the main project is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Use composition instead of inheritance. Move your error management code to a separate class and keep an instance of that class in the classes that need it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that in your definition of DBEngine every DBEngine IS the same ErrorManager, or can you think of the possibility that in future you want to create a subclass of DBEngine that uses a different manager, or even a class that is a DBEngine in every way except for the ErrorManager?

People tend to inherit instead of compose because it is less typing. They forget that future changes will be more problematic.

The advantage of composition above inheritance, is that you can decide to let your class use a different error handler while all your million users of your class (hey, you make perfectly usable classes!) don't have to see anything from this change.

Another advantage of composition is that you control what functions of the error handler can be used by users of your class. Are you sure that users of your class can use any function of an ErrorManager without interfering with your DBEngine class?

Indeed the disadvantage of composition is that you'll have to do some typing. But usually this is only a call to the corresponding function of the errormanager.

```
interface IErrorHandler
{
    void Warning();
    void Error();
}

class VeryGoodErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    public void Warning()
    {
        // a lot of difficult code
    }
    public void Error()
    {
        // even more difficult code
    }
}

class DBEngine : IErrorHandler
{
    private IErorHandler myErrorHandler = new VeryGoodErrorHandler()

    public void Warning()
    {
        this.myErrorHandler.Warning();
    }
    public void Error()
    {
        this.myErrorHandler.Error();
    }
```

Notice that you don't have to recode all the difficult code, just call the handler.

Also notice that the changes are minimal if you want to change your engine class such that is uses the class NotSoGoodErrorHandler : IErrorHanlder?

Notice that you without big changes you can let the creator of your DBEngine which error handler to use:

```
class DBEngine : IErrorHandler
{
    private IErorHandler myErrorHandler = null;

    public DBEngine()
    {   // use default error handler:
        myErrorHandler = new VeryGoodErrorHandler();
    }
    public DBEngine(IErrorHandler userProvidedErrorHandler)
    {   // use default error handler:
        myErrorHandler = userProvidedErrorHandler
    }

            public void Warning()
    {
        this.myErrorHandler.Warning();
    }
    public void Error()
    {
        this.myErrorHandler.Error();
    }
}
```

See the changes are minimal. If your class isn't really a special kind of another class, don't use inheritance. Composition may take some extra typing now, but it greatly enhances the possibilities for change and reusability.

Answer (score 0):

If your error handling is static you can do it via an extension method:

```
public interface IErrorHandling { }

public static void HandleError(this IErrorHandling errorHandler, string errorMessage)
{
    Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
}

public class YourClass : YourSuperClass, IErrorHandling
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        this.HandleError("Error, I did something!");
    }
}
```

You can omit the `this` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create the ErrorHandler inside your class:

```
public inteface IErrorHandler
{
    void HandleError(string errorMessage);
}

public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    public void HandleError(string errorMessage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
    }
}

public class YourClass: YourSuperClass
{
    public IErrorHandler ErrorHandler { get; } = new ErrorHandler();

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        this.ErrorHandler.HandleError("Error, I did something!");
    }
}
```